# Asterisk automatic hang up when I try to call

Tags: asterisk

I just set up a server with Asterisk set up but when I try to make a VoIP call the line automatically drops...

I use CommPeak as a SIP provider and Bria for the interface

Here's my sip.conf:

```
[general]
allowguest=no
context=default
bindport=5060
dtmfmode=rfc2833
disallow=all
allow=alaw
allow=ulaw
allow=gsm
allow=g723
allow=g726
allow=speex

; replace INBOUND_SIP_USERNAME and INBOUND_SIP_PASSWORD
; with your Inbound SIP Registration credentials
register => USERNAME:PASSWORD@trunk

[9786324654]
type=friend
host=dynamic
context=from-internal
username=USERNAME
password=PASSWORD
qualify=yes
nat=force_rport,comedia

[8763442]
type=friend
host=dynamic
context=from-internal
username=USERNAME
password=PASSWORD
qualify=yes
nat=force_rport,comedia

[trunk]
type=peer
host=eu1.sip.commpeak.com  ; Europe POP
;host=amn.st.ssl7.net ; North America POP
context=from-trunk
qualify=yes
defaultuser=USER
remotesecret=SECRET
```

My CommPeak has enough credit to make calls

My logs:

```
[Jul 25 14:37:52] Asterisk 13.21.0 built by root @ localhost on a x86_64 running Linux on 2021-07-25 14:29:26 UTC
[Jul 25 14:37:52] NOTICE[20963] cdr.c: CDR simple logging enabled.
[Jul 25 14:37:52] NOTICE[20963] loader.c: 227 modules will be loaded.
[Jul 25 14:37:52] WARNING[20963] res_phoneprov.c: Unable to find a valid server address or name.
[Jul 25 14:37:52] ERROR[20963] ari/config.c: No configured users for ARI
[Jul 25 14:37:52] NOTICE[20963] confbridge/conf_config_parser.c: Adding default_menu menu to app_confbridge
[Jul 25 14:37:52] NOTICE[20963] cel_custom.c: No mappings found in cel_custom.conf. Not logging CEL to custom CSVs.
[Jul 25 14:37:52] WARNING[20963] res_hep_rtcp.c: res_hep is not loaded or running; declining module load
```

Comment: Check your logs.

Comment: Nothing interesting

Comment: I don't even see an attempt to make a phone call there. Turn up the verbosity and debug levels.